# want to copy paste chart as a object in PPT using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerpoint

I have total 70 slides which i am getting by changing slicer,My code is working to open ppt delete object(which is back dated chart from excel) then copy paste charts in ppt. Issue is 70 slides is pasting after 1st 70 slides.bcz it is  already having title and footer.Instead of 70 i am getting 140 slides.1st 70 with title and footer anf next 70 which is newly pasted.
I want to update these 70 slides in last month ppt.(keeping remaining title footer as it is)

```
For Each chr in Sheets("tab1").ChartObjects
  ppApp.Activepresentation.Slides.Add ppApp.ActivePresentation.slides.Count
  ppApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide ppApp.AvtivePresentation.Slides.Count
  chr.Select
  With ActiveChart.Parent
 .Height= 500
 .Width=900

  End With

  ActiveChart.CopyPicture 
  Appearance:=xlScreen,Size:=xlPrinter,Format"=xlPicture
  ppApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste

  ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters,True
  ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignmiddles,True

Next chr
ppApp.Visible=True

Next item
```

Comment: Where in your code is the chart deleted? Your code adds as many slides as charts exist in `Sheets("tab1")` and copies the iterated active chart `Picture` in the newly created slides... I think it would be good to better explain **in words** what you try accomplishing... Do you want **adding slides** and paste there the iterated charts picture? Or want only iterate between existing slides, delete existing picture (chart picture) and paste the updated one instead? If so, (this last assumption), should we assume that the slides order is identic with the charts one?

Comment: I want to replace old charts which i pasted as object with new charts.But keeping title and footer as it is.

Comment: I want to replace old charts which i pasted as object with new charts.But keeping title and footer as it is.By my code its appending in next slide like pasting start from 71st slide.Its not updating in slide which starts from 1st to 70th